# what is the friction (static or kinetic) between two blocks in contact

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

please will someone can explain this to me:

given the coefficient of statics of kinetic friction, when two blocks are in contact and do not slip on each other, which friction do we use? static or kinetic friction.

Comment: Are they moving or are they static one w/r to,the other?

Comment: they are both moving but are on top of each other.

Comment: Then  nothing more needs to be said.  Which one applies to moving objects and whichone to static objects?

Comment: kinetic friction applied to moving object. but in the solution of the question, it is written since there is no slip, the two objects have the same acceleration and they use the coefficient of static friction.

Comment: there is no relative motion between the objects ...

Comment: -1. Not useful, and no research effort. Why do you think they are called static and kinetic? These terms mean *relative to each other.* If it was relative to something else then the amount of friction would depend on what object you choose as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

when the blocks are not moving with respect to each other even on application of force, then the magnitude of static friction is equal to the external applied force which is trying to bring the relative motion.we use coeff. of static friction.